# Override Joomla Component Template

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-template

I am using this URL to access the raw HTML of a component:

```
/index.php?option=com_downloadform&tmpl=component
```

However it also returns the document type, title tags, head tags etc.

Is there a way to return only the content between `<body>` and `</body>`?

Thanks,

Ian

Comment: Do you want everything inside the `<body>` (this includes nav, header, footer, all modules etc) or just the content that your component outputs?

Comment: Sorry just the component output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your template folder, create a file (e.g. raw.php) and inside that file place only:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Then, you can use **/index.php?option=com_downloadform&tmpl=raw** to access the raw output of the component. The tmpl parameter in your link must be the name of the file without the extension.