# Joomla Component override template

Tags: view, joomla, components, overriding

I'm writing a Joomla 2.5 or 3.x component
which make data elaboration and returns some data.

I want that work as a service that is invoked and returns data 
(eg 
I call **www.mysite.com?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview**

and result for example my json data ..or xml or what i need after my elaboration
)

so i need that my output view is raw.
i need no template and no css or js..
only my result..

but now the results are inserted into the template

Is it possible?...

I tried to create a RAW mode in my template
like [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978067/override-joomla-component-template) .

this works but is not what I want
but it is a dirty solution
because it work if the url i have to call is like ...
*www.mysite.com~....~&**tmpl=raw***

I'd like my component can output as raw.

Thanks

Comment: You will find these useful: [raw format view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905567/joomla-3-how-do-i-use-the-raw-format-without-adding-format-raw-to-the-url/20914010#20914010) ,and, [json output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16715801/joomla-component-controller-not-returning-json).

Comment: Or you can just output data and die in view.raw.php

Answer (score 1):

1. Create RAW view `views/[myview]/view.raw.php` inside your component
2. In requests require RAW format 
   `index.php?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&format=raw`.

*Like in [`com_banners/views/tracks/view.raw.php`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/administrator/components/com_banners/views/tracks/view.raw.php).*

Sames goes for `JSON` and `XML`.

Here's a list of generic document formats: [`libraries/joomla/document`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/tree/staging/libraries/joomla/document)

- `feed`
- `html`
- `image`
- `json`
- `opensearch`
- `raw`
- `xml`

To use JSON format in response, I recommend new [`JResponseJson`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/response/json.php) class:

```
// Anything that may be serialized with json_encode or an Exception
$data = array('some' => 'data');

echo new JResponseJson($data);
```